# Differences between openembedded-core and poky

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

We want to build a embedded Linux device using Yocto which is SELinux Enabled.

I was looking at meta-selinux layer Dependencies.

> ### Dependencies
>
> This layer depends on the openembedded-core metadata and the
>   meta-python and meta-oe layers from the meta-openembedded repository.

When it is referring to 'openembedded-core' does it mean poky

[git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky](http://git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky)

or

https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core

What are the differences between poky and openembedded-core, i don't see bitbake in openembedded-core

Answer (score 4):

OpenEmbedded/Yocto Project is a superset project, from this superset, a subset (poky) is created so people can get a taste of OE.

Poky distribution is made using components from OE, demo BSPs, helper scripts to easily setup build environment, QEMU emulator to test the image, and the bitbake task scheduler. This make poky a ready-to-cook subset of OpenEmbedded (OE) that helps users to understand the build system and to create their own Linux distribution possibly based on Poky distro.

Comment: Do you know why they felt the need to export a subset? What is the boundary that determines if a package should go into OE or poky (for example: license, graphical vs non-graphical, etc.)?

Comment: @JessyDiamondExum OpenEmbedded is a large kitchen and Poky is a dish let say Suchi which is an outcome of a few ingredients picked from the kitchen and the way of making (recipe) using tools like an oven (bitbake) etcetera. Now you can just decide which part should go where. A package is an ingredient so it should go to OE, instructions to combine selective ingredients will go to Poky side.

Answer (score 3):

Poky is a reference distribution of the Yocto Project. It contains the OpenEmbedded Build System (BitBake and OpenEmbedded Core) as well as a set of metadata to get you started building your own distro.  See https://www.yoctoproject.org/software-item/poky/

Comment: So, using poky or openembedded-core makes no difference?

Comment: You can use openembedded-core from poky. Openembedded is one thing, and yocto is a distribution who makes use of the openembedded-core layer. IMO you should. But read more about the topic and try and error.

Comment: There's also a meta-poky layer in the poky project, which is the layer that contains the poky distribution configs. Since I'm still a beginner, I'm not quite sure of the difference of "poky" and the poky layer. I think when talking about "poky", one thinks of all the layer that poky needs, plus the meta-poky layer itself. Other yocto distributions also have git repositories where they pull other layers, and if one talks about building or depending on such a distribution, one would implicitly mean not only the distributions own "actual" layer, but also its pulled dependencies.

Comment: That's also true about openembedded-core. That project contains the "meta" layer, and also a skeleton example layer and others. However when talking about the openembedded-core layer, one specifically mean the meta/ layer, I think. However, I feel (as a beginner!) that it's not so clear what "openembedded-core metadata" means.